# @FunctionalInterface inheritance

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Say I have the following interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface First {
   int fun(int a);
}
```

and also

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Second extends First {
   default int fun(int a) { fun(a, a); }

   int fun(int a, int b);
}
```

Then if I have a method somewhere that takes a `First` I can do, for example:

```
methodThatTakeFirst(val -> val + 1);
```

But I also want to be able to pass a `Second`, like:

```
methodThatTakeFirst((v1, v2) -> v2 * v2);
```

However this only works if I cast the lambda like this:

```
methodThatTakeFirst((Second) (v1, v2) -> v2 * v2);
```

My question is: is there a way to design this pattern without having to cast the lambdas to the subinterface? Or what would be the most elegant way to handle this scenarios?

Comment: ...Why would you want to do this?  What purpose would this serve?  Why wouldn't you just define either `default` functions in your functional interface to handle extra behaviors instead of imposing what looks like unnecessary inheritance?

Comment: Without the cast, there is no way for the compiler to infer that you want a lambda implementation of `Second`. Casting is the best/easiest way to tell the compiler that, so casting *is* the most elegant way to handle this scenario.

Comment: @Makoto good point, assume that First is from a library that cannot be altered, but extended

Comment: Even if `First` cannot be altered, what is gained by passing an implementation of `Second`, especially a lambda?  The only thing that method `methodThatTakeFirst()` can reasonably do with its argument is invoke the `fun(int a)` method, which is defaulted in `Second`.  You would be better off defining a concrete implementation of `First`, and passing an ordinary instance of that.

Comment: sometimes I want to pass a lambda that uses both params, sometimes only one

Answer (score 0):

You could overload `methodThatTakeFirst`, so that it also accepts an instance of `Second` as an argument, and *delegate* to `methodThatTakeFirst(First first)`:

```
void methodThatTakeFirst(First first) {
    // play with first
}

void methodThatTakeFirst(Second second) {
    methodThatTakeFirst((First) second); // casting necessary
}
```

The cast is crucial, so that the compiler actually delegates to `methodThatTakeFirst(First first)`, otherwise you'd end up with a `StackOverflowError`.

Whether this is a good design or not, I don't know, but I think it's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add another lambda?

```
  void secondMethod(Second second) {
      methodThatTakeFirst(x-> second.fun(x,x)); 
  }
```